# Iterate over multiple Meteor Collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I would like to iterate over multiple Mongo collections in meteor (server side). First I would like to check if a collections has any documents.

My code so far:

```
     var isEmptyCollection = function(name) {
          if(name.find().count() === 0) {
             return true
          } else {
             return false
          }
        };

        var mycollections = ["CollectionOne", "CollectionTwo", "CollectionThree"];


        for (var i = 0; i < mycollections.length; i++) {
            if (isEmptyCollection(mycollections[i])) {
        } else {
            var data = mycollections[i].find({},{fieldOne: 1}).fetch();
            console.log(data);
        }
```

I get this Error:

```
    TypeError: Object CollectionOne has no method 'find'....
```

How can I iterate over collections / check in a loop if a collection has any values?

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743729/mongodb-find-if-a-collection-is-empty-node-js) to be sure if your collection has any value or is it empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array of collections contains a lot of strings, but it should contain a list of collection objects. Try changing the array assignment to:

```
var mycollections = [CollectionOne, CollectionTwo, CollectionThree];
```

I'm assuming you've defined these using `Mongo.Collection`.

Comment: Yes those are `Mongo.Collections`. Thank you. That solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

`mycollections[i]` would be the string "CollectionOne". 
Use `global[ mycollections[i] ]` to get a reference to the actual collection.

E.g: `global[ mycollections[i] ].find().count()`

On the client `window[ mycollections[i] ]` would be it.