# check empty table with mongoose statement nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to check empty table or existing mongo table and write code like this

```
if (table isn't empty) { /*code*/ }
```

How can I do this?

```
 else if (table isn't empty) {
   Intake.find(function(err, intakes) {
     if (err)
       res.send(err);
     res.json(intakes);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Please add query codes and more codes to your answer for better helping

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb, find if a collection is empty, node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743729/mongodb-find-if-a-collection-is-empty-node-js)